# issue with searching through an array and storing the result on a new array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a coin flip game, however I am trying to do things a bit different than what I have seen others do with their code. Essentially I want to store the possible outcomes of a coinflip in an array called before and then create a function that searches through that array and pushes the value of the result of the coin flip into a new array called after. Here is my code so far, but I am getting an error when I am trying to run it.

```js
var before = ["heads" , "tails"];
var after = []

function coinFlip() {
  let repeat = 1
  for (let i = 0; i <= repeat; i++) {
after.push(before[Math.floor(Math.random() * before.length)])

  }
}
coinFlip() //call function
console.log(after);
```

Comment: *What* error are you getting?

Comment: I edited the code block into a snippet.  It works if you actually call `coinFlip()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var before = ["heads" , "tails"];
var after = []

function coinFlip() {
  let repeat = 1
  for (let i = 0; i < repeat; i++) {
    after.push(before[Math.floor(Math.random() * before.length)])
  }
}
coinFlip();
console.log(after);
```

Two things that you're missing, first is you've defined `coinFlip` function but forgotten to invoke it. Second is that instead of `i <= repeat`, it should be `i < repeat` so that it respect the number of repeats that you've defined in `repeat`

Comment: Thank you. That worked. I removed the "<=" and replaced it with "<"